# Objects spawn on cursor rather than in the origin

Tags: objects, 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I just got Blender 3 days ago, and I messed something up. Whenever I create a new object, it spawns wherever my cursor currently is. But instead, I want it to spawn at the original world origin. Any help?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "spawn" in this context, however new objects (from Shift+A menu) in Blender are added at the 3D cursor location.

Comment: All objects are created where the 3D cursor is. That is one of it's functions.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the 3D cursor right? According to [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html), this is exactly what 3D cursor does:

> The 3D Cursor is used as the origin for any added object, can be used and moved with the snap tool, and is an option for the pivot point.

If you need a shortcut to place the 3D cursor back at the center, try using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I thought I remember every object spawning at the xyz origin, not on my cursor (yes the 3D cursor). I did some configuration where now every object I create is placed on my cursor. If that is the default, correct me, because that's not what I thought. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: As @sacrish says, by default, added objects get placed at the 3D cursor, not the world origin.  If there's a setting or add-on to change this, I've never seen it.  However, immediately after adding an object at the 3D cursor, you can press Alt-G to clear its location transform which will move it to the world origin.